# Conditionally show items of Nav widget

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to add a condition to menu items so when a user logs in, he will see menu depending on his `user_type`. Here is my code.

```
Nav::widget([
    'encodeLabels' => false,
    'options' => ['class' => 'sidebar-menu'],
    'items' => [
    // I want to insert condition here
    [
        'label' => '<span class="fa fa-fw fa-globe"></span> Menu1',
        'url' => ['/menu1'],
    ],
    [
        'label' => '<span class="fa fa-fw fa-list-alt"></span> Menu2',
        'url' => ['/menu2'],
    ],
]);
```

Some users can access the `menu1` and others can access only the `menu2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** For single item use `visible` property (info is available [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html#$items-detail)):

```
[
    'label' => '<span class="fa fa-fw fa-globe"></span> Menu1',
    'url' => ['/menu1'],
    'visible' => $condition,
],
```

**2)** As an alternative you can build array before rendering the widget and conditionally include / exclude some items of array dependending on conditions.

```
$items = [];

if ($condition) {
    $items[] = ...
} else {
    ...
}

echo Nav::widget([
    'items' => $items,
]);
```

See for example how menu items are formed in [advanced template frontend layout](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/views/layouts/main.php).

Comment: is the condition true or false?

Comment: Yes, you can pass any expression that returns `boolean` value there. So it can be either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I made something like this by extending Nav class, using own access check function.

```
class AccessNav extends Nav
{
    public function renderItem($item)
    {
        $url = ArrayHelper::getValue($item, 'url', '#');
        if( PermissionManager::checkAccessByUrl($url))
        {
            return parent::renderItem($item);
        }
    }
}
```