# Yii2 ?: condition in layouts/main.php

Tags: yii2, conditional-statements

I want to write a condition like this, for example:

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? (

   ['label' => 'Sign Up', 'url' => ['/site/signup']]

):(
   //do nothing
)
```

Can `?:` condition be without `else` part?

**EDIT:**

It is sent to the array `'items' => []`  and that's why the code below doesn't work:

```
 if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)(       
       ['label' => 'Sign Up', 'url' => ['/site/signup']];      
)
```

The full code:

```
NavBar::begin([
        //somecode
    ]);
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => [

            Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? (

                ['label' => 'Sign Up', 'url' => ['/site/signup']]

            ):(
                //HOW TO DO NOTHING HERE???
            )

        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: okay, can you please update your question with the more code in which current code is located? It may be the method

Comment: i have just done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You may write this as -

```
['label' => 'Sign Up', 'url' => ['/site/signup'], 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest ]
```

Comment: it doesn't work, because it is sent to the array `'items' => []`

Comment: try `null` instead of `[]`

Comment: the same error. I was trying to use `['label' => false]`. It works, but creates a space between the other labels and it is bad...

Answer (score 2):

it's possibe if you use condition in array,..

maybe you can check this link.

[Conditionally show items of Nav widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618420/conditionally-show-items-of-nav-widget)

maybe useful
CMIIW

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is an useful link